# Symmetric limits

Tags: limits, integration

I read that you can use something called a "symmetric limit" to evaluate the improper integral of sin(x) as 0, something that I attempted by taking the right hand improper integral and adding it to the L.H. improper integral... Only the limits don't exist. Could someone explain how a "symmetric limit" can be put to practical use?

Comment: please read for improper integrals this  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Improper_integral

Comment: actually there does not exist term  symmetric limit,i have tried to find it and could not find,that why i have post just link for improper  integral

Comment: I found it in the Collins math dictionary, though without suitable explanation, so perhaps it is simply obscure, archaic, etc.

Comment: The wikipedia post was not very enlightening on the subject...

Comment: yes just  author  introduced  this term,but  simply in wikipedia  there is explained  this one.i have posted  link i will upload   exmaple  that i think is  symmetric limit,

Comment: i have  uploaded pictures,it is what  are you   looking for?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For improper Riemann integral over $(-\infty,\infty)$. The symmetric limit means
taking the limit of corresponding proper Riemann integral symmetrically.

$$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} f(x) dx\;\stackrel{def}{=}\;\lim_{R\to\infty} \int_{-R}^R f(x)dx$$

You can view this as a special case of taking the [Cauchy principal value](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy_principal_value) of corresponding integral.

***Note*** please note that above is not the general definition of improper Riemann integral. However, I'm not aware of any standard notation to distinguish the symmetric limit version from the general version of definition.

Comment: Thank you! That is surely what I am looking for!

Comment: ok good that you found what  you are looking for